# How many ways are there to get the number with the sum of $n$ nonnegative integers with constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Imagine I have $n$ nonnegative integers $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $\dots$, $a_n$. I also have two constants $M$ and $B$. How many sets of nonnegative $(v_1, v_2, v_3 ,\dots, v_n)$ are there so that they satisfy: $$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \cdots + a_nv_n \le B,$$ and $$v_1+v_2+v_3 + \cdots +v_n = M.$$

Comment: What have you done so far?  Can you solve it when $n=2?$  Why is this question interesting?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, see the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write equations in a more readable way.

Comment: I encountered a computer programming algorithms problem somewhere which is formulated differently but goes down to this.